# php update record repeat region

Tags: php, mysql

As previously stated in my last question on WHAT a cron job is, I'm now trying to write one but seem to get a problem. This is the closest I've gotten. I want to update every record in the database by one more than what it already has.

Example if the field is 30, then when this script is run then it will become 31. But I have MULTIPLE fields and I want all of them to increment by one.

This is what I've currently wrote, but it doesn't work, but I DO get an echo of "Record Updated Successfully" but nothing changes. If I change it so that $Age = $Test and then I plug in a random number for the ID it will end up equaling Test. If I have it say $Age = $NewAge and the random ID, it changes the variable in my database to be 302. I have NO clue where it's pulling that random 302.

Any suggestions?

This is my code below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "RR";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sqlSelect = "SELECT id, Age FROM Horse";
$result = $conn->query($sqlSelect);

do{
$id = $row['id'];
$Age = $row['Age'];
$NewAge = $Age + 1;
$Test = 200;


echo $id, ' ', $Age, ' ', $NewAge; ?> <br/>

<?php 
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Horse SET Age='$NewAge' WHERE id='$id'";


}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc());


if ($conn->query($sqlUpdate) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why not just do `UPDATE Horse SET Age = Age + 1`?

Comment: i assume your `Age` column is int?  try this `UPDATE Horse SET Age=Age + 1 WHERE id='$id'`

Comment: That doesn't result in any change at all. I tried that and don't know why that wouldn't work. @roullie

Comment: @rjdown that didn't work, any other suggestion?

Comment: @LondonKallie "does not work" is not a useful feedback. Pls be more specific as to what error message you receive or what unexpected behaviour you encounter. Your code essentially equals to `UPDATE Horse SET Age = Age + 1` which is a valid sql statement. If this does not produce the expected results, then the fault is not with sql logic, but with sg else we cannot determine without a proper feedback from you. Btw storing the age and regularly updating it is not really recommended, store the date of birth instead and calculate the age on the fly.

Comment: @Shadow I've been doing that from the beginning, but the point of my site is a virtual game and when two virtual animals on my site have a baby, the date of birth is placed ahead of time (for gestation period) The calculation for age can't be determined on the fly there because that code is on a profile page for the animal. My game is going to have a game-time so logically I thought having a cron job just update everything at Midnight would work fine.

Comment: As for doing     UPDATE Horse SET Age = Age + 1 the query at the bottom still says "Record Updated successfully" but nothing in my server actually updates.

Comment: Then you need to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very vague and hard to understand, but as @rjdown said, this will update **ALL** rows in the database and increment `Age` by 1.

**Note**: there is no need for fetching the records from database, nor looping over them. Just one line of SQL will update ALL rows.

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "RR";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Horse SET Age = Age + 1";

if ($conn->query($sqlUpdate) === TRUE) {
echo "All records updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```